# How can I check the syntax of Jython script without executing it?

Tags: java, python, jython

I'd like to implement python syntax checking in a Java application without and external dependency of the `python` executable.

I downloaded the [Jython standalone jar](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html) and I'm looking for a behavior similar to Python's `-m py_compile` option.

Comment: `-m` runs a module as a script, so it also executes ist, it doesn't just do syntax checking.

Comment: [`ast.parse()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse) parses a given source without executing it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it? Works fine here.

```
# java -jar jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar -m py_compile run.py && echo 'good'
good
```